# How to create Menu Items in Metro Apps in windows8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Iam trying to develop metro appications in windows8 using visual studio 2012RC .Here i need Menu Items like a column wise,And each Item need to navigate separate page if user click on it.Here i tried to give u my application scenario.Any working examples are really helpful to me.

Thank you.

MetroApplication:

```
----------------------------------
|        |                       |
| Item1  |-->Page1               |
|=========                       |
|        |-->Page2               |
| Item2  |                       |
|=========                       |
|        |                       |
| Item3  |-->Page3               |
|=========                       |
|  Item4 |-->Page4               |
|        |                       |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: Is this a menu to be display on screen all the time, or do you mean a popup menu?  There are different approaches you can take depending what the answer to that question is.

Comment: @ZombieSheep,thank you for ur reply.actually it is a menu and needs to be display on screen all the time for my entire application.can u give me sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vertical StackPanel that contains bunch of Buttons: each button will then navigate to the dedicated page.